# Prevent copying data to usb devices in Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, permissions

How can i prevent copying data to usb devices in Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Is there anything like "Group policy" in Windows or similiar?

Comment: Related: [*Deny non-root users to mount devices*](https://superuser.com/q/1245759/432690).

Comment: USB sticks with FAT filesystems are auto-mounted with specific group and user-ids, so you have to find out which kind of auto-mounting your Ubuntu uses, and then you can modify the ids or set permissions, if the auto-mounting system allows it (Debian `usbmount` does, not sure about systemd-stuff).

Answer (score 0):

There may well be better, more bullet proof ways of doing it, but playing arround on my Ubuntu 16.04 system -

Ubuntu mounts disks at /media/USERNAME/XXXXXXXX so by changing the write permissions for /media/USERNAME they will not be able to access the mount point.  You can do this (as root) using chmod 700 /media/USERNAME

A better way - depending on your needs - might be to stop the usb_storage module from loading, making USB disks unrecogniseable.  You can do this with a command like

```
 echo "blacklist usb-storage" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-usb.conf
```

And rebooting your system.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403798/set-removable-media-usb-drive-permissions-to-a-specific-group for a more complex and comprehensive method.

Comment: Thank you! But one more question..can i give chmod 755 (only read & execute ) permission by this way?

Comment: Probably not - that would depend on the filesystem on the USB drive. I'm not a a PC to check, but I'm pretty sure Ubuntu mounts the drive with the permissions of person who is logged in, and more specific  file perms will override the parent mount point details provided the user can read that mount point.